# Use of computed property as constants

Tags: swift, constants, computed-properties

i am just new to swift and was wondering that is it good option to use computed property for the constants like in given example.

As in iOS development, we usually define constants in .pch file for notification key string in objective. So the below option makes any sense?

```
struct NotificationsKey {
    static var CreateProfilePageDidMoved:String {return "CreateProfilePageDidMoved"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for your example to be computed or a `var`. Instead do:

```
struct NotificationsKey {
    static let CreateProfilePageDidMoved = "CreateProfilePageDidMoved"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the way you declared the constant in swift.what i want to know that using your technique, there would a string allocated in start of application. Does this happens same if we access via computed property? Logically it doesn't look like we are allocating something using computed property. 
is there any difference related to memory allocation in both above ways?

Comment: The string has to be stored somewhere, one way or another it's going to take up memory. The computed property is a bit more transparent, and doesn't make (as) obvious the fact that it's a constant.